# Convert string into time and compare 2 of them

Tags: excel, vba, date, time

I have the following strings:

```
01/04/2019 11:32:45
```

and

```
01/04/2019 11:38:13
```

I want to be able to compare both the times and then add the result to a cell.

Am I better splitting the string using the gap in the middle and then trying to convert it to a readable time ?

Whats the easiest way to do this?

Searched a few forums and they all seem to be slightly over the top for what I thought would be a simple task

cheers

Comment: hi. what u want to compare ?

Comment: end result i would like to compare the difference between the 2 times. 

I have a massive sheet of 2500+ of these and i'm struggling

Comment: And the sheet contains strings, not dates?

Comment: Dates/times are just numbers in Excel. The date is the integer bit, the time the fraction.

Comment: long story short I have individual transcripts in individual cells and I have split the lines of the transcript into an array. but need a way of comparing the first 2 date stamps in the array.

Comment: @SJR the date stamp is part of a bigger string. i have managed to strip it down to just the date stamp but it's still classed as a string and VBA can't compare them

Comment: Can you use text to columns? I think we need a better idea of your data to help.

Comment: Are your date/time format `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: @ScottCraner always dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 1):

This compares the ***time*** elements of two strings, (subtracting one from the other) and returning the difference formatted to hours, minutes and seconds:

```
Dim starttime As String
Dim endtime As String

starttime = "01/04/2019 11:32:45"
endtime = "01/04/2019 11:38:13"

timedif = TimeValue(endtime) - TimeValue(starttime)
Debug.Print Format(timedif, "hh:MM:ss")
```

---

If you want to have separate ***days also***, you could use:

```
timedatedif = (DateValue(endtime) + TimeValue(endtime)) - (DateValue(starttime) +TimeValue(starttime))
Debug.Print Format(timedatedif, "dd:hh:MM:ss")
```

Comment: Thats it, superb. does it get more complicated if the 2 dates were different ? For example the first one on 01/04/2019 and then the second on 02/04/2019 ? or would this still work ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have strings that contain a date, best bet is to convert them to real `Date` values.

You can use the function `CDate` to convert strings to dates, however, there are quite some pitfalls, e.g. depending on the regional settings of your computer, the date format (and the order of day, month and year) may change and `CDate` will try to respect these settings. If your code runs in another part of the world, the same input may result in different dates. This is probably the reason you found *complicated* code that splits the strings into pieces to get the single parts of a date.

A date is stored as `Double` value. The integer part of the number defines the date, starting at 31.12.1899. The fractional part represents the time. To get the difference between two dates, you can simply subtract them.

Now the question comes up what you want to do with the difference. You could write a UDF that returns this difference and format your cell to just display the time part. Just think carefully if you can have differences > 1 day. Or you could multiply the difference with 24 to get number of hours, or by 24*60 to get the minutes.

A UDF could look like

```
Function TimeDiff(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Date
    Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date
    d1 = CDate(s1)
    d2 = CDate(s2)
    TimeDiff = IIf(d1 > d2, d1 - d2, d2 - d1)
End Function
```

Assuming your date string are in A1 and B1, you could write a formula `=TimeDiff(A1, B1)` into cell C1.

An alternative to get the number of minutes (note the different return value type):

```
Function TimeDiffInMinutes(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Long
    Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date, diff As Date
    d1 = CDate(s1)
    d2 = CDate(s2)
    Diff = IIf(d1 > d2, d1 - d2, d2 - d1)
    TimeDiffInMinutes = Diff * 24 * 60
End Function
```

Both functions will have to no issues when the dates are different.

If your input format is always in the form `01/04/2019 11:38:13` but CDate will confuse 1st of April with 4th of January, you can write a small function that splits up the string manually and creates a date out of it. Just replace the call to `CDate` by a call to your own conversion function:

```
Function stringToDate(s As String) As Date

    Dim pieces() As String, datePieces() As String, timePieces() As String

    pieces = Split(s, " ")
    datePieces = Split(pieces(0), "/")
    timePieces = Split(pieces(1), ":")

    stringToDate = DateSerial(datePieces(2), datePieces(1), datePieces(0)) _
                 + TimeSerial(timePieces(0), timePieces(1), timePieces(2))
End Function
```